# Angular does not always receive response

Tags: angularjs, node.js, get

I am making a get request to a server. The problem is that angular does not always receive a response. I do not understand why. Here is my code.

```
<button ng-click="getDuration();" ng-init="limit=15;">

 $http.get("/getDuration:"+$scope.duration+":"+$scope.date+":"+$scope.time)
    .then(function (response) {
      $scope.arr = response.data;

    }, function(response){

    });
//server
app.get('/getDuration:duration', function(req, res){

//some date processing
conn.query('SELECT * FROM thumbnail where thumbnail_date BETWEEN ? AND ?',[date, new_date], function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (var i in rows) {
        arr.push(rows[i].thumbnail_id);
    }

    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
    console.log("Sending data");
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(myJsonString);

});
```

});

The browser only refreshes. But sometimes I get the response. What am I doing wrong?The thing is I always get the request on my server side.Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you get an error in the response? Try to add `console.log(response)` in the second `function(response)` that is triggered when an error happens

Comment: it gives me data: null, but on the server side the json has a value. weird.

Comment: At least now you know the error isn't in client side. Sorry but I'm not a node.js export, but check the `conn.query()` function, error should be there